# Wordpress Multisite - Create Default Post and New Category On New Site Install

Tags: posts, categories, multisite, installation, customization

I've looked around quite a bit, but couldn't find help with creating a new, initial blog post and new category (or renaming the default category) once a new sub-domain has been installed.

I've added a script in the mu-plugins folder and have tried to find code for, and figure this out but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Can this be done? I've found and successfully used the code to create new pages, but that's as far as I can go.

Comment: You could include an XML file which when imported, adds pages and categories etc.

Comment: Thanks Brad, maybe I should search for how to "include an XML file" but that would take me away from this topic, unless you post a link to how to do that, and what format to do that in.

Comment: I've figured it out, I've changed the post type to POST rather than PAGE and it worked but I'm not sure if this is the actual right way.

This seems to have worked for creating a new blog post:


 // create new blog post
$page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
'post_title' => 'Welcome To My Blog',
'post_name' => 'welcome-to-my-blog',
'post_content' => 'Thank you for visiting.',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_author' => $user_id, 
'post_type' => 'post',
  ));